# pass parameter to View Component after table row click

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Inside a normal View, we are populating a table via the model with this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if (item.PartnerSubscriptionID > 0)
   {
     <tr id='customlistid_@item.CustomList.ListID'>
       <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick='ListCustomEdit("@item.CustomList.ListID")'>
         <i class='fas fa-users'></i>
        </button>                                    
      </td>
       <td style="display:none">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomList.ListID)</td>
       <td style="text-align:left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomList.ListName)</td>
       <td><button id='btnDelete' type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='ListCustomDeleteConfirm(" @item.CustomList.ListID ")'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button></td>
      </tr>
    }
}
```

On the same page I have a View Component. It works when I hard code the ListID like this:

```
<div class="col-8">
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("ListCustomMembers" ,  new {ListID = 7 } )
</div>
```

But we need the ID to be passed in when the user clicks the row. Ie, where we currently have the `onclick=ListCustomEdit()` we need to refresh the `View Component` with the correct ID.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewComponent` is rendered on the server side, so when the user clicks in the browser, you need to send another request to the server to render and return the `ViewComponent` with the new parameter, for which you can use a `controller`.
Create an `action` in the `controller` you want to return the `ViewComponent`, then update the view as shown below after clicking the button using `jquery`

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult GetNewList(int listId)
    {
        return ViewComponent("ListCustomMembers", new { listId });
    }
}
```

on the view side:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick='ListCustomEdit("@item.CustomList.ListID")'>

<div class="col-8" id="ListCustomMembers">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ListCustomMembers" ,  new {ListID = 7 } )
</div>


<script>
   function ListCustomEdit(listId) {
       $.get('/test/GetNewList/?listId=' + listId,
           function(result) {
               $("#ListCustomMembers").html(result);
           });
      }
</script>
```